# Why can't I get .uniqueId() to work with all elements of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of `<a class="anchor"></a>` elements. Why can't I get `uniqueId()` to work on them? Here is what I have:

```
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
```

```js
$(".anchor").each(function() {
  $(this).uniqueId();
});
```

I have also tried:

```
this.uniqueId();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `uniqueId()` is a jQueryUI method, so have you included the jQueryUI library as well as jQuery itself? Check the console for errors. Although I'd suggest that if you structure your HTML properly you don't need to auto-generate an `id` at all.

Comment: I tested it out with JQuery UI. It works fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ys36qp5a/

Comment: @zfrisch taking that a step further, you don't need `each()`: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g95aebxz/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right, but it's straight from OP. Just wanted to show that it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
$('.anchor').uniqueId();
```

Demo:

```js
$('.anchor').uniqueId();

$('.anchor').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor">This</a>
```

However, your code should lead to the same result. As mentioned in the comments, make sure you have included both jQuery and jQuery UI's libraries.